# HoverOver Pop Up C#

Tags: c#, jquery, hover, mvcgrid

I'm new to c# and I am trying to work with some code that is already built. I want to place a hover over blubble when someone clicks on a column header for a table. I have the following code. In the example below one of the columns has the title ID and below is some data for my table. Let say that the user hovers their mouse or clicks on the "ID" header. I want to display some text with a hover over screen. Any ideas? I've done some research but I can't find anything that has worked. I'm trying to decide if I just need to rewrite the table. One of the things I did was add something like this .Attributes(c => new Dictionary { { "class", "tooltip" }, { "data-content", ".tooltip-content" } }); but this adds the pop up the cells below the header but not the header.

```
@Html.Pager((IPagination)Model.CustomersWithCurrentVolumes)

@(Html.Grid(Model.CustomersWithCurrentVolumes)
   .Columns(col =>
  {
    col.For(c => c.Customer.Generation).Named("Generation"); 
    col.For(c => c.Customer.Level).Named("LVL");
    col.For(c => c.Customer.CustomerID).Named("ID");
    col.Custom(c => c.Customer.FirstName).Named("First Name");
```

Comment: This doesn't really show any work for actually displaying a pop over.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 One of the things I did was add something like this     .Attributes(c => new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "tooltip" }, { "data-content", ".tooltip-content" } }); but this adds the pop up the cells below the header but not the header.

Comment: Please add that to the question.